# Could not find a match for URL /ServercCustomRestApi error occur when i am trying to call one Salesforce org custom rest API from another org

Tags: rest-api

Could not find a match for URL /ServercCustomRestApi error occur when i am trying to call one Salesforce org custom rest API from another org..

Salesforce Org "A" having Custom REST API

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ServerCustomRestApi/*')
global class ServerResource
{
@HttpGet
  global static string show()
  {           
         return 'This is Server Account method';                
  }
}
```

Salesforce org "B" having code for calling

```
HttpRequest request =new HttpRequest(); 
request.setEndPoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/ServerCustomRestApi');   
request.setMethod('GET'); 
request.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth '+AccessToken);
Http htp = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = htp.send(request);
Response =  res.getBody();
```

but after running this code i am getting this error

> [{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"Could not find a match for URL
>   /ServerCustomRestApi"}]

Comment: You quote three different names in your question: ServerCustomRestApi, RestCustomRestApi and ServerRestApi. Start by checking that you are using the same name in the called and calling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Keith C, i have make it correct..... actually it was incorrect here not on my console.

and i also found the issue:

actually i am using package name as MyPackageAC at the server account ... that's why error occur. 
change the end point:
request.setEndPoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/MyPackageAC/ServerCustomRestApi');